# How to comment & uncomment multiple line SQL code in DataGrip IDE

Tags: datagrip

I would like to comment out queries with a keyboard shortcut, like so

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM Academics
   WHERE Academic_id = 1
```

To become

```
--SELECT * 
   --FROM Academics
   --WHERE Academic_id = 1
```

Answer (score 20):

```
/*
 SELECT * 
   FROM Academics
   WHERE Academic_id = 1
*/
```

Same as:

```
--SELECT * 
   --FROM Academics
   --WHERE Academic_id = 1
```

If you're working with SSMS, use <kbd>CTRL + K</kbd>, then press <kbd>C</kbd> for "comment" or <kbd>U</kbd> for "uncomment"

Comment: He is asking about DataGrip, not SSMS:

Answer (score 15):

1. Select SQL code

   `SELECT TOP 3 *  FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Customerid ='4de3092d03b742f3b2b88cf6fe0b09d0'`
2. Press <kbd>CTRL + /</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD + /</kbd>  on Mac) on the keyboard
3. Code will be commented

   `--SELECT TOP 3 *  --FROM CUSTOMER --WHERE Customerid ='4de3092d03b742f3b2b88cf6fe0b09d0'`
4. If you need to uncomment it, you need to mark commented code and press the same keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL + /</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD + /</kbd> on Mac)  on the keyboard Code will become uncommented again:

   `SELECT TOP 3 *  FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Customerid ='4de3092d03b742f3b2b88cf6fe0b09d0'`

Comment: `Cmd + /` works on BigQuery editor too

Answer (score 4):

You are using SSMS, you can go to:

Tools - Options - Keyboard
JUST change keyboard mapping scheme to Vs Code

then Ctrl + / works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJwpI.png)

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for how to comment out queries can be found [Here](http://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/datagrip/docs/DataGrip_keymap.pdf).

But in short, press Ctrl + slash (/) together to toggle between commented/uncommented on highlight lines.

Ctrl + Shift + Slash can be used to comment/uncomment blocks of queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SSMS, you can go to:

`Tools` - `Options` - `Keyboard` (under Environment)

- type in 'comment' in the 'Show Commands containing:"
- select `Edit.CommentSelection`
- select '`Text Editor`' under "Use new shortcut in:"
- Assign a shortcut key that you like (ex: `Ctrl + /`) --> `Assign` --> Click Okay

If you want to uncomment then choose Edit.UncommentSelection and follow the step above, but it will need to be assigned to a different key other than `Ctrl + /`, may be use `Ctrl+'`

Step to change CommentSelection shortcut key

Comment: He is asking about datagripd. Check 'tags' below the post.

Answer (score 1):

***You are using SSMS, then you can go to:***

1).use  for single line

```
--
```

shortcut  CTRL + K, CTRL + C.

2).use for multiline for     /*

here your selected text

*/

Thanks